How to overcome the label overlapping in donut graph?
The labels in the graph is overlapping with each other when the value size is small
The graph with the overlapping labels
This is the code I have tried.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ["225 g flour", "90 g sugar", "1 egg", "60 g butter", "100 ml milk", "1/2 package of yeast", "abcd", "efg", "hik"]

sizes = [225, 90, 1, 5, 200, 1, 3, 100, 5]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

explode = [0.01] * len(sizes)  # Small explosion for all segments

wedges, texts = ax.pie(sizes, explode=explode, radius=1.2, startangle=90, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.4))

centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.40, fc='white')

ax.add_artist(centre_circle)

kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"), zorder=0, va="center")


for i, p in enumerate(wedges):

    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1) / 2. + p.theta1
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    yc = np.arcsin(y)/(np.pi/2)
    horizontalalignment = {1: "left", -1: "right"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = f"angle,angleA=0,angleB={ang}"
   kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(0.8*x, 0.8*y), xytext=((1+(len(labels[i])%2)*0.6)*np.sign(x), 1.4 * yc), 
horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, fontsize=10, **kw)

ax.set_title("A Donut Graph", fontsize=14)

plt.show
()

